# Can I sell Bitcoin bought in 2014?

Tags: market

In 2014, my cousin told me about bitcoins. I thought they were pretty cool, so I went to coinbase and bought 10 at the time (I was 14 at the time). Then, my best friends grandparents passed away and I forgot about them ever since.

Now I am 17, and today I logged on and am shocked to see coinbase says my 10 bitcoins are worth $60,000 dollars. How can this be? I am tempted to cash it out but feel this is illegal and the goverment is going to be on me. Should I tell coinbase there is a bug in the system or something? Has anyone had a similar situation?

Answer (score 3):

> 10 bitcoins are worth $60,000 dollars. How can this be?

Indeed, the price has skyrocketed recently, each bitcoin is worth around $6092.00 USD as of writing this answer, it's not a glitch.

> I am tempted to cash it out but feel this is illegal and the goverment is going to be on me.

It's not illegal to sell or buy bitcoins in most countries, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_bitcoin_by_country_or_territory
You should probably just ensure you pay tax on the income.